# How can I get address of literals?

Tags: c, literals, memory-address

Is there any way to get address of literals?

For example:

```
floar r = 1.0;
float area = r * r * 3.14;
float* addressOfPI = ? // TODO: Address of 3.14 in previous line
```

Comment: You are not storing the value `3.14` in any variable how will you get the address?

Comment: If what you want was feasible you would have it wrong: `3.14` is a value of type `double`.

Comment: haha: `*addressofPI = 2; x = 3.14 * 21; /* is x == 42? */`

Comment: @pmg On VAX Fortran yes, it is! Brings back memories ... all bad.

Comment: Oh boy! I'm glad I never learned Fortran like that @DavidSchwartz

Answer (score 3):

Literals like `3.14` are rvalues, they don't have an address. This is the difference between lvalue and rvalue.

Answer (score 1):

In C, taking the address of a floating constant (OP's "literal") or integer constant is not available.   It is an "rvalue" or "value of an expression" and lacks an address.

Yet taking the address of a compound literal (C99) is OK.

```
// Add more types as needed
#define constant_address(X) _Generic((X), \
  double  : &((double){X}), \
  float   : &((float){X}), \
  unsigned: &((unsigned){X}), \
  int     : &((int){X}), \
  default: 0 \
  )

int main(void) {
  #define MY_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
  double *addr_pi = constant_address(MY_PI);
  printf("%f %p\n", *constant_address(MY_PI), (void *)constant_address(MY_PI));
  printf("%f %p\n", *addr_pi, (void *)addr_pi);
  printf("%8d %p\n", *constant_address(1234), (void *)constant_address(1234));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
3.141593 0x28cbb0
3.141593 0x28cba8
    1234 0x28cbc0
```

To be clear: In C parlance, code *can* take the address of a literal. Yet `3.14` is not a literal.  It is a *floating constant*.